# 33% Width for all device using Bootstrap for Responsive

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want take 1/3 width of a single row for all device.
Is there any other option to do instead of this code....

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Bootstrap is defined mobile first, you should be able to just define the `xs` size, like so:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-8"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use col-xs-4 it can act md-4 and lg-4 on larger devices.
you cannot use md-8 there is only 12 grids.